# Google Script - Removing Else statement properly so it skips/ignores

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I have a checklist, column C indicates which test is automated by "enabled" or "disabled" written in the cells.

Further down the row is a column for the the Pass / Empty column for each test.

I have code that looks for if Enabled in column C, in X column on that row, mark as Pass automatically (or 'P' in my case).

The problem: If C column contains "Disabled" but also a Pass, when I run the script it replaces that Pass with an empty cell. How can I change the else statement to just ignore that cell and leave whatever is in it for anything but Enabled condition is met

```
function autoPassPC() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Aug 2020');
  

  //  What to put in the test result
  var values1 = "P";
  // Where to look for Auto:
  var values2 = sheet.getRange("C10:C15" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // Keyword to look for in Auto: column
  var putValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values2.length; i++) {
    if (values2[i][0] === "Enabled") {
      putValues.push([values1]);
    } else {
      putValues.push([""]);
    }
  }

  //  Put value1 inside row, column# for test result
  sheet.getRange(10, 25, putValues.length, 1).setValues(putValues);
}
```

Basically how do I get rid of

```
} else {
  putValues.push([""]);
}
```

properly? Just deleting this causes the script to put 'P' on every single row. Just want it to ignore the cells instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `else` statement will actually skip the row, but as soon as you skip a row, all following values in `putValues` will be on the wrong row. Instead of "skipping", try pushing the already existing value into `putValues`.

```
function autoPassPC() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Aug 2020');
  

  //  What to put in the test result
  var values1 = "P";
  // Where to look for Auto:
  var enabledDisabled = sheet.getRange("C10:C15" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var testResultsRange = sheet.getRange("X10:X15" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var testResults = testResultsRange.getValues();
  
  // Keyword to look for in Auto: column
  var putValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < enabledDisabled.length; i++) {
    if (enabledDisabled[i][0] === "Enabled") {
      putValues.push([values1]);
    } else {
      putValues.push([testResults[i][0]]); // Push the existing cell value
    }
  }

  //  Put value1 inside row, column# for test result
  testResultsRange.setValues(putValues);
}
```

You could also try getting the entire table at once thus having only one `getValues()` call.

Comment: Amazing this seems to work exactly how I wanted thanks so much. 

Something in the code seems to be creating rows in the document though?

Comment: @Leffer This has to do with the way you were defining the ranges, which I honestly didn't understand, but assumed you were doing it for a specific reason. If the last row is 20, then `C10:C15" + sheet.getLastRow()` is going to result in "C10:C1520". Do you know how to resolve from here?

Comment: Oh lol I removed the + sheet.getLastRow() and simple using the range I need directly in the C and X seems to work good now. Thank so much Diego much appreciated